# How to inject a path into a type="file" field using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver

I'm having a problem sending a path to a file to a type="file" field (file upload scenario) which handles a bit weird.

I'm using webDriver with Java and do not wish to use 3rd party tools such as autoIT.

Please note that trying element.sendKeys does NOT work, as this field by default opens an OS browse-to-file type window which cannot be handled by webDriver.

You can see below how it looks like:

```
<input type="file" size="40" name="filename">
```

This does not expand further and represents the field + Browse button!

The only solution I found out how this could work for the above scenario (without sendKeys and autoIT) is by JavaScript injection, but I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks,

Vivian

Comment: Using `element.sendKeys()` is the right approach. The browser drivers should be smart enough to work around the OS file selection dialog in this case. I can assure you that method is not globally broken; the WebDriver project has tests for this exact scenario that have been executed thousands of times without issue.

Comment: Hi Jim! I saw your other comments on this problem. I know that webDriver is able to do this, that's why I was puzzled at first. The problem is how it handles locator-wise these fields, as I've seen many examples of people fighting these upload type=file fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments guys!

The solution, was sendKeys indeed, but only after generating the most retarded xpath in human history with firepath.

Be careful, my previous attempts didn't work as the xpath used before `"//input..."`, though valid, was sending keys to the Browse button, which xpath-wise is the same element as the field (what sorcery is this?).

So yeah, for everyone that also has problems with file upload forms via webDriver - get a retarded xpath and element.sendKeys.

Cheers!